# Briny/salty smell from fuel tank?

Tags: fuel-system, golf, fuel-tank

I've had some trouble with my lifter pump and so I removed the back seat of my Mk1 Golf/Rabbit to access the pump and fuel tank.

As I was removing the 'lid' to access the tank the aged seal/gasket thing around this lid disintegrated.

Now, I've noticed a kind of briny, almost salty smell emanating from within the car at times.

Is this due to fuel going bad from being exposed to air now that there is no gasket?

Comment: Gas or Diesel??

Comment: @Moab gas (unleaded)

Comment: "Is this due to fuel going bad from being exposed to air now that there is no gasket?" there is always air in the tank, so no.

Comment: How old is the gas in the tank? Gas can go rancid but takes 9 months or more.

Comment: @Moab no older then normal. Car is not a daily but driven several times a week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so the problem was that, due to a faulty fuel gauge sender, I over filled the tank. And since the seal around the top of the 'hatch' had partially disintegrated, well this happened:

[image]

When parked on an angle, fuel was just flowing from the top of the tank :/

Comment: Wow, scary.  Great post.  TY +1